# Submit parameterized query as plain query with parameters in place

Tags: java, spring

I have a java + spring framework application which works with Redshift. Right now code is mapping HttpServletRequest to MapSqlParameterSource and submit as a parameterized query. It works well only one issue that Redshift doesn't optimize some queries (where table is sorted by column) well with this approach. If I submit same query with parameters as part of sql statement performance is better.
I need an example how to replace parameters before submitting sql to the redshift.

instead

```
select column1
  from table1
where create_date between :from_date and :end_date
from_date='2017-01-01'
end_date='2017-01-01'
```

submit

```
select column1
  from table1
where create_date between '2017-01-01' and '2017-02-01'
```